# Issues with suggestion list in botframework Webchat React

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, autocomplete, react-redux, botframework

I just added autosuggestion/autocomplete function in my bot-framework web chat(v-4) using react.js. But there are some issues i need to fix;

**1.)** While getting the suggestions i want to make the words which i type into the webchat to be Bold in the resulting suggestion list. I did that but the problem i'm facing now is that its only making the first letter as bold(as you can see in the image) i want to make it bold even if its inside a sentance.

**2.)** When i select an option from the suggestion list it has to be closed. It closes the other options but the selected option is not.(as shown in the image). I want to close that too.

**3.)** I want to make my up/down arrow for selecting options from the suggestion list.

Please find the images in below links,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good job on this so far. It looks like you have three questions here. I want to make sure I understand question 1 first. You say "i want to make it bold even if its inside a sentance." In your screenshot you've typed t and the letter "t" is bold in each suggestion only as the first letter of the suggestion. Can you explain what letters you want bold in "Smartphone/Tablet Troubleshooting"? Do you just want the first t to be bold (at the end of Smart) or do you want every t to be bold? Also do you want it to be lowercase? For your second question you'll need to provide the "handle click" code.

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney i want to make the firstly occuring letter bold. Means in Smartphone/Tablet Troubleshooting 't' is first occured in smar't',  which should be bold. And for the 2nd question please find the handle click code attached above.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this isn't what we need. Your second question says that when you click an option, the other options disappear but the one you clicked remains. I was thinking there was some code in the click handler that was making the options disappear incorrectly, but now I'm thinking that you don't have any code to make any options disappear and what's happening is that when you set the send box it triggers the same code to make options appear as when you type on the keyboard, but now that you've inputted a long phrase there's only one matching suggestion.

Comment: Since you'll want to reset the auto-suggestions component back to the invisible state that it was in originally, we'll need to see the code that makes it appear originally. Can you post that?

Comment: @KyleDelaney No there is no code. Could you please help me doing this. I'm already spending too much time on this.

Comment: I'm trying to help you right now, but you need to help me help you. It looks like your suggestions are in a div element with a class called SuggestionParent. How is that getting added to your DOM? Is a new one created each time and added on top of the old one? Does a new one replace the old one? Does the same one stay in use?  Please edit the question to include the code that handles that element.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Can you help me how to get keypress in webchat. I want my up/down keys to select options from the suggestion list. How can i do that?

Comment: Yes, I can see that's question 3, but I'm not done asking about question 2 yet. Once you've given me the information I need then I can post answers to all three questions as an answer. Do you understand what I'm asking for?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I've done the 2nd one.So leave it. You only need to focus on the 3rd question. Is there any additional info i need to add?

Comment: Are you saying you're dropping question 1 as well? About question 3, I just need to know if you already have some kind of "highlighting" functionality that you can use as a visual indicator that a suggestion is "selected." For example, do the suggestions respond visually to mouse over or mouse down? If you already have a visual indicator for mouse events then you may be able to use the same thing to indicate that a suggestion is selected when using the keyboard. Are you wanting an solution for showing that an option is selected, or are you just wanting to know how to receive keyboard input?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes, there is highlighting functionality while selecting a suggestion with mouse over. And it is done using css. Now what i'm asking is, how can i enable it using up/down arrow keys in keyboard.

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have attached my whole code above, that you're asking too much questions and i'm really running out of time. Please note that I don't have anything else to attach more than this. If you can, please help me with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It would have been nice to see the CSS because I presume that's how you're doing your on-hover styling. I'm working on a solution for you now, based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931389/scroll-with-keyboards-up-down-arrows-keys-in-react

Comment: @KyleDelaney Ok. please find the attached css above.

Comment: @KyleDelaney what about the solution? I'm waiting for your reply. any updates?

Comment: Why did you remove your code?

Comment: @KyleDelaney yeas i had to. Due to some policy issues. sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, there may be two ways to do this. To do it the React way, you could use `indexOf` to find the index of the user text in the suggestion and then split the text into multiple React elements with one of them being bolded. If you want to use `replace` like you're currently doing then this may be a good opportunity to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
<div className="SuggestionParent" id="Suggestion1">
  {this.state.suggestions.map(suggestion => (
    <div className="Suggestion" onClick={this.handleSuggestionClick} >
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getSuggestionHtml(suggestion)} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

The "dangerous" warning is because you need to make sure you don't allow the user to provide any of the potential values that can go in the inner HTML or else they could inject script tags. As long as your suggestions are being drawn from a fixed database and the data is secure then you might be okay. Otherwise you would have to sanitize the HTML and in that case it would probably be easier to just not use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` at all. If we do set the inner HTML, then we can use `replace` to just directly apply HTML tags to the string:

```
getSuggestionHtml(suggestion) {
  const lowerCaseSuggestion = suggestion.toLowerCase();
  return {
    __html: lowerCaseSuggestion.includes(this.state.suggestionTypedText) ? lowerCaseSuggestion
      .replace(this.state.suggestionTypedText, `<b>${this.state.suggestionTypedText}</b>`) : lowerCaseSuggestion
  };
}
```

For your second question, you said you've already solved it. I can see that you're using a Boolean switch to temporarily turn off the way you respond to the WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX action.

For your third question, there are a lot of design considerations that you have to ask yourself about when figuring out how your UI is going to work, like "What happens if the user mouses over the suggestions while they're using the arrow keys?" and "Should the highlighted suggestion be previewed in the send box before the user presses enter?" I was hoping to find a preexisting React autocomplete component that you could use instead of building your own because that would already address all these potential pitfalls. Unfortunately, the two prominent React autocomplete packages ([here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete) and [here](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/)) both have the same two problems:

1. They're not currently being maintained
2. The targeted input is included in the component so you don't get to connect the component to a preexisting input.

However, they are both open source so we can model our own autocomplete functionality after them. I'll guide you through the basic functionality and you can expand on that as you please.

Keyboard events are generally handled in React using the `onKeyDown` property. I've placed it on an element that contains both Web Chat and your suggestions parent:

```
<div className={ROOT_CSS} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}>
  <div className={WEB_CHAT_CSS + ''}>
    <ReactWebChat
```

That will handle all key presses, so you'll need a way to route to the function for the correct key. You could use a `switch` statement but the source code for [react-autocomplete](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/Autocomplete.js) uses a lookup object and I think that's smart.

```
keyDownHandlers = {
  ArrowDown(event) {
    this.moveHighlight(event, 1);
  },
  ArrowUp(event) {
    this.moveHighlight(event, -1);
  },
  Enter(event) {
    const {suggestions} = this.state;
    if (!suggestions.length) {
      // menu is closed so there is no selection to accept -> do nothing
      return
    }
    event.preventDefault()
    this.applySuggestion(suggestions[this.state.highlightedIndex]);
  },
}

handleKeyDown(event) {
  if (this.keyDownHandlers[event.key])
  this.keyDownHandlers[event.key].call(this, event)
}
```

I've centralized the functionality for the up and down arrows into one function: `moveHighlight`. You will need to define a new property in your state to keep track of which suggestion has been selected by the keyboard. I'm keeping the name `highlightedIndex` from react-autocomplete.

```
moveHighlight(event, direction) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { highlightedIndex, suggestions } = this.state;
  if (!suggestions.length) return;
  let newIndex = (highlightedIndex + direction + suggestions.length) % suggestions.length;
  if (newIndex !== highlightedIndex) {
    this.setState({
      highlightedIndex: newIndex,
    });
  }
}
```

For the enter key to apply a suggestion, you'll want to centralize your functionality so that it works the same way as a mouse click.

```
async handleSuggestionClick(event) {
  await this.applySuggestion(event.currentTarget.textContent);
}

async applySuggestion(newValue) {
  await this.setState({ typingChecking: "false", suggestions: [], highlightedIndex: 0 });
  this.state.suggestionCallback.dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
    payload: {
      text: newValue,
    }
  });
  await this.setState({ typingChecking: "true" });
}
```

Finally, make sure the `highlightedIndex` property is used to render the highlighted index differently.

```
getSuggestionCss(index) {
  return index === this.state.highlightedIndex ? HIGHLIGHTED_CSS : SUGGESTION_CSS;
}

. . .

<div className="SuggestionParent" id="Suggestion1">
  {this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => (
    <div className={this.getSuggestionCss(index)} key={index} onClick={this.handleSuggestionClick} >
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.getSuggestionHtml(suggestion)} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to change the styleset of adaptive cards. I  want to change the button placement and title color. But i'm unable to do so with css. As the adaptive cards are using a common 'p' for all text blocks, so if i change the title color every text block color will be changed. How can i solve this?

Comment: You could try using the [HostConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/host-config#foregroundcolorsconfig)

Comment: So how can I do that using Hostconfig. As I'm calling my botframework webchat to the react front end, I dont know where should i write the code for this. Can you please help me by explaining what to do.

Comment: You might be interested in this comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2034#issuecomment-501818238

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney yeah, but its about recreating the hostconfig file and still i didnt get a clear picture about doing so. I only want to change the button orientation and the title color of the adaptive cards. Is there any other ways to achieve that?

Comment: There are certainly other ways, but there aren't any easier ways

Comment: Hi Kyle, the app is showing the below error whenever i try to send a msg via the application. And there is no problem if i select the message from suggeston list. What is the reason for this problem? Please help
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action "WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX", reducer "sendBoxValue" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

Comment: And one more thing, when choosing the selection using highliting i want to send the message by clicking the desired suggestion. Now if i click the suggestion it comes to the send box/input area and i have to press enter again to send that message. How can i change it to send the message just by clicking the appropriate suggestion?

Comment: Sorry Thomas. It's not really convenient to help you with new problems by commenting on old issues. You could post a new question, but I really recommend trying to figure this out for yourself. You need to see if there's any way your code could set the send box to undefined. You know your own code better than anyone else.

Comment: Hi @kyle I'm sorry i didnt mean like that. You know the current scenario well as i explained my problems, so i thought its easier for you to help me . That's why i asked you. As you know while clicking the suggestion we are taking it to the input/text area and then we need to press enter to send the message. I just want to change it by - While clicking the suggestion the message should be sent(i.e. don't want to take it to the input area).

Comment: Just use a different action instead of WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX. I put a console.log in my Redux middleware to see when each action gets executed. You can see the actions that fire when you send a message and then send one of those actions yourself, like DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY perhaps. You can see the available actions here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions

Comment: Ok. so you mean i should use another action for that. Can i use the action with handleSuggestionClick to send the message by clicking it. What about sendMessage action?

Comment: Just try it and see. Again, please do not have an extended discussion in the comments of this old answer. Ask a new question if you still need help.

Comment: hey Kyle, do you have any idea on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716870/how-can-i-clear-the-chat-input-box-after-sending-the-messagefrom-suggestion-in please help if you can

Comment: There's no need to comment here about that. You used the appropriate tags so my team is aware of it.