# How to take a key up/down in web chat using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, botframework, bots

I am currently doing bot-framework web chat application using react js.I want to know how can i take a key up/down. As i want to  select or highlight through suggestion list using arrow keys. My code which i used for the react component is attached below, PFA,

```
async handleSuggestionClick(val) {
  const newValue = val.currentTarget.textContent;

  await this.setState({ typingChecking: "false" },
    () => { console.log(this.state.typingChecking) });

  await this.setState({ suggestions: [] },
    () => { console.log(this.state.suggestions) });


  this.state.suggestionCallback.dispatch({
    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
    payload: {
        text: newValue,
    }
  });
  await this.setState({ typingChecking: "true" },
    () => { console.log(this.state.typingChecking) });
}

<div className="react-container webchat" >
    <ReactWebChat directLine={this.state.directLine} 
      webSocket={true}  
      store={this.state.storeValue} 
      sendTypingIndicator={true} />
    <div className="SuggestionParent" id="Suggestion1">
      {this.state.suggestions.map(suggestion => (
        <div className="Suggestion" 
          onClick={this.handleSuggestionClick} 
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
          {suggestion
            .toLowerCase()        
            .startsWith(this.state.suggestionTypedText) ? 
               (<div>
                  <b> 
                    {this.state.suggestionTypedText}
                  </b>
                  {suggestion
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .replace(this.state.suggestionTypedText, "")}
                </div>) : 
                (<div>{suggestion}</div>
              )
           }
        </div>
      ))
     }
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036865/react-how-to-navigate-through-list-by-arrow-keys

Comment: @sv12 i tried the solution from your link but it did'nt worked for me

Comment: Could you please include the code of your component?

Comment: @MohammadDohadwala it is attached with the question please find.

Comment: @Rasnam.v - Are you working on this project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524754/issues-with-suggestion-list-in-botframework-webchat-react

Comment: @Kyle Delaney yes i am working on that...can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answer to your duplicate issue: [Issues with suggestion list in botframework Webchat React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524754/issues-with-suggestion-list-in-botframework-webchat-react)

> Keyboard events are generally handled in React using the `onKeyDown`
>   property. I've placed it on an element that contains both Web Chat and
>   your suggestions parent:
>
> ```
> <div className={ROOT_CSS} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}>
>   <div className={WEB_CHAT_CSS + ''}>
>     <ReactWebChat
> ```
>
> That will handle all key presses, so you'll need a way to route to the
>   function for the correct key. You could use a `switch` statement but
>   the source code for [react-autocomplete][3] uses a lookup object and I
>   think that's smart.
>
> ```
> keyDownHandlers = {
>   ArrowDown(event) {
>     this.moveHighlight(event, 1);
>   },
>   ArrowUp(event) {
>     this.moveHighlight(event, -1);
>   },
>   Enter(event) {
>     const {suggestions} = this.state;
>     if (!suggestions.length) {
>       // menu is closed so there is no selection to accept -> do nothing
>       return
>     }
>     event.preventDefault()
>     this.applySuggestion(suggestions[this.state.highlightedIndex]);
>   },
> }
>
> handleKeyDown(event) {
>   if (this.keyDownHandlers[event.key])
>   this.keyDownHandlers[event.key].call(this, event)
> }
> ```
>
> I've centralized the functionality for the up and down arrows into one
>   function: `moveHighlight`. You will need to define a new property in
>   your state to keep track of which suggestion has been selected by the
>   keyboard. I'm keeping the name `highlightedIndex` from
>   react-autocomplete.
>
> ```
> moveHighlight(event, direction) {
>   event.preventDefault();
>   const { highlightedIndex, suggestions } = this.state;
>   if (!suggestions.length) return;
>   let newIndex = (highlightedIndex + direction + suggestions.length) % suggestions.length;
>   if (newIndex !== highlightedIndex) {
>     this.setState({
>       highlightedIndex: newIndex,
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```